# How can I transform an iterator trait object of concrete types into an iterator trait object of trait objects?

Tags: reference, rust, iterator, traits

I have a trait which contains a function to return an iterator over references to another trait, like:

```
pub trait ParentInterface {
    fn children<'a>(&'a self) -> Box<dyn Iterator<Item = &'a ChildInterface>>;
}

pub trait ChildInterface {
    fn some_method(&self) -> bool;
}
```

How can an iterator of the correct type be returned when implementing this trait for a concrete type which stores a vector of concrete values?

```
pub struct ConcreteParent {
    my_children: Vec<ConcreteChild>,
}

pub struct ConcreteChild {
    my_value: bool,
}

impl ParentInterface for ConcreteParent {
    fn children<'a>(&'a self) -> Box<dyn Iterator<Item = &'a ChildInterface>> {
        Box::new(self.my_children.iter()) // Compiler error!
    }
}

impl ChildInterface for ConcreteChild {
    fn some_method(&self) -> bool {
        self.my_value
    }
}
```

The above example yields a compiler error for Rust 2018:

```
error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<std::slice::Iter<'_, ConcreteChild> as std::iter::Iterator>::Item == &dyn ChildInterface`
  --> src/lib.rs:19:9
   |
19 |         Box::new(self.my_children.iter()) // Compiler error!
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `ConcreteChild`, found trait ChildInterface
   |
   = note: expected type `&ConcreteChild`
              found type `&dyn ChildInterface`
   = note: required for the cast to the object type `dyn std::iter::Iterator<Item = &dyn ChildInterface>`
```

I assume that `my_children.iter()` returns an iterator with the wrong `Item` type (the concrete type instead of the trait type) - how can this be solved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, a trait object is bounded by `'static`. You must specify the lifetime `'a` and then you can correctly map the iterator ([source](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-02-advanced-lifetimes.html#inference-of-trait-object-lifetimes)):

```rust
pub trait ParentInterface {
    fn children<'a>(&'a self) -> Box<dyn Iterator<Item = &'a dyn ChildInterface> + 'a>;
}

pub trait ChildInterface {
    fn some_method(&self) -> bool;
}

pub struct ConcreteParent {
    my_children: Vec<ConcreteChild>,
}

pub struct ConcreteChild {
    my_value: bool,
}

impl ParentInterface for ConcreteParent {
    fn children<'a>(&'a self) -> Box<dyn Iterator<Item = &'a dyn ChildInterface> + 'a> {
        Box::new(self.my_children.iter().map(|c| c as &'a dyn ChildInterface))
    }
}

impl ChildInterface for ConcreteChild {
    fn some_method(&self) -> bool {
        self.my_value
    }
}
```

Note the changes:

- The reference bounds of the iterator are `'a`, just like the items:

  ```rust
  dyn Iterator</*...*/> + 'a
  ```
- Each concrete type is mapped to a trait object:

  ```rust
  .map(|c| c as &'a dyn ChildInterface)
  ```

  Note that you can simplify the notation to let the inference work: `.map(|c| c as _)`

You can simplify further by using the lifetime `'_`:

```rust
pub trait ParentInterface {
    fn children(&self) -> Box<dyn Iterator<Item = &dyn ChildInterface> + '_>;
}

// ...

impl ParentInterface for ConcreteParent {
    fn children(&self) -> Box<dyn Iterator<Item = &dyn ChildInterface> + '_> {
        Box::new(self.my_children.iter().map(|c| c as _))
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you elaborate or refer to documentation on why `+ 'a` is required for the Iterator return type? Why is it assumed `'static` by default?

Comment: @Cybran I've added the source, but there is no explanation about the "why"